# Raspberry Pi 5 Fan Connector Compatibility?

Tags: connectors, pi-5

I'm trying to figure out for sure if the Raspberry Pi 5's fan connector is compatible with a Noctua NF-A4x10 5V. The voltage is correct, at least. Now I'm trying to make sure that the board is fine with it's amperage and that the pinout is the same as the standard PWM connectors. The documentation for the Pi 5 calls the connector a "four-pin JST PWM fan connector" and details it's pinout as shown in the image below.

[image: Pinout]

The noctua fan in question can be found  [here](https://noctua.at/en/nf-a4x10-5v-pwm/specification). It's voltage matches the 5V of the Pi 5's documentation above.

I also fed this into ChatGPT just to see and got this.

[image: ChatGPT's Response]

This is as far as I've gotten. I dont want to take the AI's reply as gospel here so does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Some info https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=359778

Comment: Seems he had to make a custom "JST* cable. Not sure if I can take that as a definitive "no" to if it's just standard PWM.

Comment: Pretty sure fans are standardized this way; if you've ever build a desktop motherboards have a slew of these connectors (albeit usually 12V) and you can just buy fans of whatever size.  I can't see why the Pi folks would, eg., want to swap the tach and PWM lines or something.

Comment: I think so too, but I'm hesitant to try my fan until I'm sure. I dont want to overload the header or anything.